# Django Restframework, Forward relationship serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class GO_BIDS(models.Model):

    GO = models.ForeignKey(GO_PROFILE)
    GO_money = models.CharField()
    GO_currency = models.CharField()

class GO_PROFILE(models.Model):

    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Name = models.CharField()
    Photo = models.CharField()
    Phone = models.CharField()
```

My Serializers looks like this:

```
class GO_PROFILESerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = GO_PROFILE
        fields = ('Name', 'Photo')


class GO_BIDSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    gprofile = GO_PROFILESerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GO_BIDS
        fields = ('id','GO_money','GO_currency','gprofile')
```

I'd like to get some sort of the following structure:

```
"GO_BIDS": [
            {
                "id": 3, 
                "GO": {
                    "Name":  "Steve", 
                    "Photo": "myphoto.png", 
                }, 
                "GO_money": "12.00", 
                "GO_currency": "USD", 
        }]
```

I keep on getting 'GO_BIDS' object has no attribute 'gprofile'.
Any Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [Nested Relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#nested-relationships). Your `GO_BIDS` model does not have a `gprofile` attribute. Try this instead:

```
class GO_BIDSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    GO = GO_PROFILESerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = GO_BIDS
        fields = ('id','GO_money','GO_currency','GO')
```

Comment: Thanks, I get 'GO_PROFILE' object is not iterable